# register:141 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript

What is this error ?

> register:141 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I want to select a combo box print in console but I see this error.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#state' function(){
             console.log('fdaa');
        });
    });
```

Comment: `'#state' function()`

Comment: what is this code?

Comment: You should put a comma after '#state'. try it like 

$(document).on('change', '#state', function() {
console.log("fdaa");
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma between `#state` and `function()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#state', function(){
             console.log('fdaa');
        });
    });
```